# Pymongo find document whose field is a substring of a given string

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, nosql

Let's say we have a collection with the following documents:

```
{_id : 1, str : 'hello'}
{_id : 2, str : 'hello world'}
{_id : 3, str : 'world'}
```

And I would like to find documents whose `str` field is a substring of `hello world!`. Is there a way to do this in pymongo?

I know the opposite - **getting documents whose field contains a string** can be done using `$regex`, but what I want is **getting documents whose field is contained by a string**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use text indexes for this, which support text search queries on string content. Text indexes can include any field whose value is a string or an array of string elements.

Here's a minimal example using pymongo:

```
# Get database connection
conn = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://localhost:27017/')
coll = conn.get_database('test').get_collection('test')

# Create text index
coll.create_index([('str',pymongo.TEXT)])

# Text search
print list(coll.find({'$text': {'$search': 'hello world'}}))
```

With your example documents, this will result in:

```
[{u'_id': 3.0, u'str': u'world'},
 {u'_id': 2.0, u'str': u'hello world'},
 {u'_id': 1.0, u'str': u'hello'}]
```

For more information, please see:

- [Text Indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-text/)
- [$text operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/)